# Can not get .html to display in a .php file

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to use PHP to allow a user to put in articles onto a certain site via a form.
The site,my code and my skills as a programmer are primitive in nature.

The user enters the input here:

```
<form action="articlepro.php" method="post">
    Title:<input type="text" name="title"><br>
    Sub-Heading:<input type="text" name="subhead"><br>
    Intro:<textarea name="intro" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br>
    Heading-1:<input type="text" name="head1"><br>
    Content-1:<textarea name="cont1" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The date is processed as such by the file articepro.php:

```
 <html>
     <body>
     <?php
         $title=$_POST["title"] . ".php";
         $createFile=fopen($title,"x+");
         $content=file_get_contents("articletemplate.php");
         echo $createFile;
         echo file_put_contents($title,$content);

         echo $createFile;
     ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

The aim of the code above is to first create a variable that stores the title from the form with the .php extension.Then the code creates a file with the same name as the $title variable.$content stores the html and php code of the file "articletemplate.php" as a string and "file put contents" puts that template into the file created earlier.
It may be of of value to know that artictemplate.php contains the template I wish for all new articles to have with bits of php that put in data as such:

```
<p><h1><?php echo $_POST["head1"];?></h1>
<?php echo $_POST["cont1"];?>
</p>
```

Now the problem I face is the fact that my code both creates the required files with the required title(Permisson:644),it also contains the intended template.BUT,I am unable to display anything when I open the created files(.php's) via URL.I either see a blank page or `"k????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????ä???????????????ä??"`
I can open them if I download the created files off the server and  change the extension to .html(cant use PHP then) though but no luck with .php or .phtml.

Webserver:Apache/2.2.24 (Unix

Comment: Why are you saving the file in the first place? Can't you just load it dynamically?

Comment: How should I go about doing that?

Comment: You should definitely go through a [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/) first to get some basis programming knowhow. You are probably doing something not the right way. I can't tell you what, because it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish with saving your file.

Comment: That was harsh.Yes,I'm probably not.I've checked the code multiple times,tried changing the extension and even altering the htaccess.Eh,was worth the try.

Comment: I am trying to somewhat automate the process of a user adding an article to a website.The saved document would contain both the preset template and the content the user added.

Comment: Saad - its a known problem here. [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Comment: Yes his question has a try, be cordial to newbies,afterall we started as them at first.

Comment: Yeah Roy, you didn't have to be so mean.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be mean, I was trying to help him with let him get thoroughly knowledge of PHP and how you should tackle certain problems.